# filter @json_decode data by date range php

Tags: php, json

im new to php and json, but have this code. it take some data from a database i have, and it work fine :)
but now im trying to make a graf and would like to see it monthly.
can any one help me whit this.

```
<?php

$out = getQuery("SELECT * FROM `pos_reports` Order by id desc Limit 0,100"); 

$out = [data] => {"total":660,"z_report_number":"2","foreign_tax_collected":0,"day":"06\/04\/2017","z_report":[{"title":"Churros","qty":1,"price":30},{"title":"Churros chokolade","qty":1,"price":35},{"title":"Raket waffle chokolade","qty":2,"price":70},{"title":"Waffle","qty":7,"price":210},{"title":"Waffle chokolade","qty":9,"price":315}],"total_for_pay_type":{"Cash":540,"Unknown":120}} [foreign_tax_collected] => 0 [shop_name] => [total_for_pay_type] => {"Cash":540,"Unknown":120} ) // this is the data i'm getting

for($i = 0; $i < count($out); $i++)
{   
$report = @json_decode($out[$i]->data);
//////////     slut på array

if ( $report->day == ($Date1<=$Date2))  {

    echo $report->day ."<br>";
}

function getQuery($qry)
{   
global $sql;

$res = array();

if ($result = $sql->query($qry)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $res[]=$row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);

}

return $res;
}

?>
```